# prove $(s\implies p)\implies((\neg s\implies p)\implies p)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

prove $(s\implies p)\implies((\neg s\implies p)\implies p)$

rules to use in this proof:

a)$(\neg A\implies \neg B)\implies (B\implies A)$

b)$(A\implies B)\implies(\neg B\implies\neg A)$

c)Deduction Theorem

d)M.Ponens

Proof:

1)$(s\implies p)$..................assumption

2)$(\neg s\implies p)$..................asum

Then i tried to get p but ended no where

So i tried  a different way

1)$(s\implies p)$..................assumption

2)$\neg p$.........................assum

3)$(s\implies p)\implies (\neg p\implies\neg s)$..................by (a)

4)$(\neg p\implies\neg s)$......................by 1,3 m.p

5)$\neg s$....................................by 2,4 m.p

But now i dont know how to get :

$\neg(\neg s\implies p)$

Because then using the d.theorem i will have proved:

$\neg p\implies \neg(\neg s\implies p)$ which by using rule (a) and m.p  will get me the desired result

Can somebody help??

Comment: Rule (a) should be $ (\neg A\implies \neg B)\implies (B\implies A)$

Answer (score 2):

Your two axioms together with Modus Ponens are not sufficient to prove this.  So you are trying to do the impossible!

How do I know this?

Remember that these formal proofs are purely syntactical beasts: all they do is "if you have a statement that looks like such-and-so, you can infer a statement that looks like this-and-that"

So, if we interpret the symbols as *intended*, then the theorem to be proven is a true statement about logic. However, what if we interpret the symbols and operators completely differently?

Well, suppose that the expressions are algebraic expressions about some domain where there are two objects, $X$ and $O$.

Also suppose that the $\neg$ and $\to$ are operators that work on these objects as provided by the following tables:

\begin{array}{c|c}
p&\neg p\\
\hline
X & O\\
O & X\\
\end{array}

(so note: this is *not* a truth-table, since we're not working with truth-functions at all in this domain.)

\begin{array}{cc|c}
p&q&p \to q\\
\hline
X & X & X\\
X & O & O\\
O & X & O\\
O & O & X\\
\end{array}

OK, so with these definitions, let's work out the value of the two axioms under each of the different value-combinations of $A$ and $B$:

\begin{array}{cc|ccc|ccc}
A&B&(\neg A \to \neg B)& \to &(B \to A)&(A \to B)&\to&(\neg B \to \neg A)\\
\hline
X & X & X & X & X & X & X & X\\
X & O & O & X & O & O & X & O\\
O & X & O & X & O & O & X & O\\
O & O & X & X & X & X & X & X\\
\end{array}

Hmm, interesting!  Note that no matter the values of $A$ and $B$, the two axioms will always evaluate to $X$.  As such, we can call them '$X$-beasts'

OK, but now notice that when we evaluate both $s$ and $p$ to $X$, the expression of the theorem $(s \to p) \to ((\neg s \to p) \to p)$ evaluates to $(X \to X) \to ((\neg X \to X) \to X) = X \to ((O \to X) \to X) = X \to (O \to X) = X \to O = O$

OK, so the theorem is *not* an $X$-beast

Finally, note that if you look at the working of the $\to$ function, you find that whenever $P$ has the value of $X$, and $p \to q$ has the value of $X$, then $q$ has the value of $X$ as well, since if $q$ would have the value of $O$, $p \to q$ would have the value of $O$ as well.  What this tells us is that if you have an expression $p$ that is an $X$-beast, and another expression $p \to q$ that is an $X$-beast, then $q$ will have to be an $X$-beast as well.  In other words, if what you start out with are $X$-beasts, then using Modus Ponens, you can only get more $X$-beasts.

In sum, given that the axioms are $X$-beasts, and given that using Modus Ponens I can only derive more $X$-beasts, I cannot derive any thing that is not an $X$-beast.  But we just saw that your theorem is not an $X$-beast. So, your theorem is not derivable.

<s>And the same is true for the Deduction Theorem: if $p$ is an $X$-beast, and $q$ is an $X$-best, then $p \to q$ will be an $X$-beast as well.</s>

OK, but what about the Deduction Theorem? Would that help?  Well, let's first point out that it is strange to say that you can use the Deduction Theorem ... when your axioms together with Modus Ponens are not sufficient to give you the Deduction Theorem!  That is, the Deduction Theorem is always a meta-theorem that says something about the capabilities of a system. And yes, for most systems the Deduction Theorem is true. But *not* for your system!  As DougSpoonwood points out in the comments: If the Deduction Theorem would be true for your system, then it would be able to derive $p \to (q \to p)$.  But it can't!

DougSpoonwood provides a very nice purely syntactical argument for this: with your axioms you can only get statements that contain an even number of atomic statements. And using Modus Ponens: if $\phi$ contains an even number of atomic statements, and $\phi \to \psi$ contains an even number of atomic statements, then $\psi$ will contain an even number of atomic statements as well. So: from your two axioms, and using Modus Ponens, you can never obtain any statement with an odd number of atomic satements. So, you can't infer $p \to (q \to p)$ .. and thus the Deduction Theorem does not hold.

In fact, using this very same argument, you can directly show that your theorem $(s \to p) \to ((\neg s \to p) \to p)$ cannot be inferred from your two axioms plus Modus Ponens either!

One last note: I could have stayed with the domain of logic and truth-values. And if I interpret the $\neg$ as normal, but I interpret the $\to$ as how we normally interpret the $\leftrightarrow$, then you'll find that the axioms are logical tautologies, that by subsequent uses of Modus Ponens and the Deduction theorem I can only get more logical tautologies, but that the theorem is not a logical tautology. So that would have worked as a demonstration as well. But I use two 'nonsense' objects $X$ and $O$ to drive the point home that there is a big difference between 'mere' syntactical symbol-manipulation and what it all means.

Comment: "And the same is true for the Deduction Theorem: if p is an X-beast, and q is an X-best, then p→q will be an X-beast as well." ???  Perhaps, unconventional use of "deduction theorem" got intended.  But, even if so, it's simply not true that (A→(B→A)) is not a X-beast... you showed that (X→(O→X)) evaluates to O.  So, the usual deduction theorem doesn't hold.  Also, the original post used usual conditional introduction, so an unconventional use probably isn't the case.  Also, the deduction theorem fails for equivalential calculus.  Your proposed alternative demonstration thus also wouldn't work.

Comment: One way to recognize that the deduction theorem fails for equivalential calculus is the meta-theorem that every pure equivalential theorem has an even number of all it's variables.  But,  (A→(B→A)) being necessary for the deduction theorem has a variable which appears an odd number of times.

Comment: " But, even if so, it's simply not true that (A→(B→A)) is not a X-beast"  Dang.  I misspoke.  It simply is not true that (A→(B→A)) is an X-beast.  It would need to hold true for an X-system to have a deduction theorem.

Comment: I think the best way to see that my axioms are not enough to prove the above theorem would be to use the other two axioms left and the deduction theorem and  see if  we can come out with a solution in the language of "->" and negation

Comment: @user149368 I ran this through Prover9 an automated theorem prover and Mace4. Apparently, the axioms *are* sufficient to prove this.  It took 50.84 seconds with no help from me to generate a proof.  8,126,050 formulas were generated.

Comment: amazing.By the way can a computer tell us ( because i am not very well acquainted; with computers) if for a simple high school algebra problem ,before even trying to solve the problem ,can be proved or not .Like the truth tables in propositional calculus??

Comment: @DougSpoonwood  Oh my!  Yes, you are absolutely right: I goofed up with the Deduction Theorem:  For some reason I was thinking of the T as: if $\Gamma_1 \vdash \phi$ and $\Gamma_2 \vdash \psi$, then $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2 \vdash \phi \to \psi$ ... but of course it isn;t. It's $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \psi$ then $\Gamma \vdash \phi \to \psi$. But yes, I was also wondering if with these two axioms and Modus Ponens alone one could even *have* a Deduction Theorem for this system ... my guess is not.  But I just went ahead as if ... though screwed up. Thanks for pointing this out!!

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I am still surprised that the two axioms plus Modus Ponens are sufficient to prove the theorem. Because not taking the Deduction Theorem as a given (and again, I don't believe the DT holds true for this system), my argument should go through: the axioms are $X$-beasts, using Modus Ponens you can only infer other $X$-beasts, and the theorem is not an $X$-beast. What exactly did you give Prover9 to work with?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Oh, I see your earlier comment about even number of variables. Yes, that makes sense: a nice purely syntactical argument that you can;t derive the theorem, or $\phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$ for that matter ... and if we can't get the latter, then clearly the DT is false for this system. OK, so did you give Prover9 $\phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$ as an additional axiom?

Comment: You're welcome Bram.  As assumptions, I gave Prover9 -P(C(x,y)) | -P(x) | P(y) for condensed detachment, because of modus ponens and Prover9's hyperresolution rule of inference. P(C(C(N(x), N(y)), C(y, x))) [a) in the original post].  P(C(C(x, y), C(N(y), N(x)))). [b) in the original post].  P(C(x, C(y, x))).  and P(C(C(x, C(y, z)), C(C(x, y), C(x, z)))). because of the deduction theorem.  So, yes, I gave a translation of "ϕ→(ψ→ϕ)" as an additional axiom.  As the goal I gave Prover9 P(C(C(x, y), C(C(N(x), y), y))).  I checked to see if P(x). was derivable, and it's not.  So...

Comment: there's no contradiction between having the deduction theorem and the first two axioms.  The deduction theorem is not an X-beast.  I don't know how many axioms this system has.  We were only given the rules of inference.  a) and b) corresponding to an axiom each might make sense.  But, the deduction theorem doesn't correspond to a unique number of axioms, since there exist many ways to prove it from sets of axioms many having a different count of the number of axioms.  So, there does not exist a way to quantify how many axioms this system has based on what we have.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to build the truth table for this expression, but here is a sequence of logical equivalences:
$$ (s\rightarrow p)\rightarrow ((\neg s \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p)$$
$$ \neg (s\rightarrow p) \vee ((\neg s \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p)$$
$$ \neg (\neg s\vee  p) \vee (( s \vee p) \rightarrow p)$$
$$  ( s \wedge \neg  p) \vee (\neg ( s \vee p) \vee p)$$
$$  ( s \wedge \neg  p) \vee ( ( \neg s \wedge \neg p) \vee p)$$
$$  ( s \wedge \neg  p) \vee  ( \neg s \wedge \neg p) \vee p$$
$$  ( (s\vee \neg s) \wedge \neg  p) \vee  p$$
$$ \neg p \vee p$$

Comment: good proof but the proof i am asking for is in a language where the logical symbol "v" does not exist ,only the "->" and the negation symbol do

Answer (score 0):

1)$(s\implies p)$..................assumption

2)$\neg p$.........................assum

3)$(s\implies p)\implies (\neg p\implies\neg s)$..................by (a)

4)$(\neg p\implies\neg s)$......................by 1,3 m.p

5)$\neg s$....................................by 2,4 m.p

6)$\neg s\implies p$..............................assum

7)$p$..........................................5,6 m.p

8)$(\neg s\implies p)\implies p$..........................6 to 7 (c)

9)$((\neg s\implies p)\implies p)\implies(\neg p\implies\neg(\neg s\implies p))$..by(b)

10)$\neg p\implies\neg(\neg s\implies p)$.......................by8,9 m.p

11)$\neg p\implies\neg(\neg s\implies p)\implies(\neg s\implies p)\implies p$..by(a)

12)$(\neg s\implies p)\implies p$................................by 10,11 m.p

13)$(s\implies p)\implies(\neg s\implies p)\implies p$............by 1 to 12 (c)

Comment: by using contradiction deduction theorem and m.p the proof should  be 6 to 7 steps

Comment: @bram28 ,well have checked my proof, is it correct or not .Because if it is correct then all you said   about my axioms ,D.T,M.P, are just mere nonsense .But thats nothing,the worst thing of all is that you got 2 upvotes and i got zero for my proof